# Connect to Azure SQL Database using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to configure connecting to azure sql using managed identity. However before, I need to connect to sql azure from visual studio using AD identity.

I have followed steps here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cef%2Cdotnet#3-modify-your-project

I have this code in console app.

```
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new 
        Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "sqlserveraddress";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "dbaddress";

        string connstring = builder.ConnectionString;

        await using var conn = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connstring)
        {
            AccessToken = await GetAzureSqlAccessToken()
        } ;

        await conn.OpenAsync();
```

As required, I have added my visual studio App service authentication identity user in sql azure db.

```
CREATE USER "user@domain.com" FROM EXTERNAL 
PROVIDER;
 ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER 
 "user@domain.com";
 ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER 
 "user@domain.com"; 
 ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER 
 "user@domain.com";
```

GO

Now if i try running my console application, I get following error.

[image]

If i try to decode the access token it shows the user I have added to sql azure. user@domain.com.

What Am I Missing here??

Comment: Did you enable azure ad auth on the azure sql database ?

Comment: Also with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` you dont need acquire manually the token, see this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication

Comment: Did you configure visual studio to use azure authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-visual-studio ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the created Managed Identity as admin in SQL Server.

Follow this: **Azure SQL Server -> Settings -> Azure Active Directory**

Now click on `Set Admin` option and search for the Managed Identity to which you want to give access.

Click on **Save**.

[image]